# Ad hoc distribution installed on phone yesterday, but not today

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to install an ad-hoc distribution package onto somebodies phone, this was sucessful with one build yesterday but a different build today won't work.

I have tried these combinations of profiles:

The first one is the XCode Code Signing Identity and the second one is  Ad-Hoc deployment signing identity

```
1) Ad hoc distribution +  Apple Push: result "signed with invalid entitlements"
2) Team provisioning + Apple Push: result installs but can't register for the push token
3) iPhone Distribution + Apple Push: result installs but can't register for the push token
4) Apple Push + Ad hoc: result "signed with invalid entitlements"
5) iOS Team Provisioning + Ad Hoc: result "signed with invalid entitlements"
```

I could keep on going and try all possible combinations, but this has worked in the past, why not now. What combination should be used?

I'm using iPhone Configuration Utitlity to install.

Comment: have you added the new devices under the provisioning profile and downloaded it and build your application using it?

Comment: Yes I did that then was able to install yesterday, but not today. But something I have just noticed is that when I view the profiles in XCode the one for the Apple Push gives disappearing, I refresh and it comes back, then 20 minutes later its vanished again. This has happened 3 times today that I've noticed and may be connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the IOS Provisioning Portal, in the Provisioning page, click the 'Download' button by your new distribution profile and it should get added to Xcode.

To check you have it, go to Xcode Organizer, Devices, then Library / Provisioning Profiles on the left.

If the automatic provisioning doesn't work, then the workaround that worked for me was to clean like you did, then disable automatic provisioning, and finally add the profiles manually.

Hope this helps. If not then comment.